# intersect 2 series

Tags: python, pandas, series

i have 2 series like this. i'll call it s1 and s2

```
1 a
1 b
1 c
2 a
2 c
3 b

s2:
1 a
1 b
2 c
3 a
```

how to combine 2 series, just keep the row have same index and value and save it into a new series? i am finding how to use combine but it seem not work. I want the result is series cause i want to use value_counts on it
Eg: i want to combine `Windowns` appear in 2 series have the same index like 1a in s1 and 1a in s2 and [index,value] will be added to s3 (result), if Windowns not in index 1a of s1 or s2, it will not be added to s3

```
s3:
1 a
1 b
2 c
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you add how looks final Series from `s1, s2` data in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) for counts in original `Series`, then filter same indices in both by [`Series.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.loc.html) with [`Index.intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html) and last count both with [`Series.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html):

```
s11 = s1.groupby([s1.index, s1]).size()
s22 = s2.groupby([s2.index, s2]).size()

idx = s11.index.intersection(s22.index)

df = s11.loc[idx].add(s22.loc[idx]).rename_axis(('idx','vals')).reset_index(name='count')
print (df)
     idx          vals  count
0      1       Windows      2
1  65112       Arduino      2
2  65112         Linux      2
3  65112  Raspberry Pi      2
4  65112       Windows      2
```

EDIT: Still wait for comment, but if there is not only `1` values in `s11` and `s22` use:

```
s11 = s1.groupby([s1.index, s1]).size()
s22 = s2.groupby([s2.index, s2]).size()

idx = s11.index.intersection(s22.index)

s3 = pd.Series(idx.get_level_values(1), idx.get_level_values(0))

print (s3)
1             Windows
65112         Arduino
65112           Linux
65112    Raspberry Pi
65112         Windows
dtype: object
```

If values are always `1` in `s11` and `s22`, it means are unique per indices use:

```
s11 = s1.to_frame().set_index('PlatformWorkedWith', append=True)
s22 = s2.to_frame().set_index('PlatformDesireNextYear', append=True)

idx = s11.index.intersection(s22.index)

s3 = pd.Series(idx.get_level_values(1), idx.get_level_values(0))

print (s3)
1             Windows
65112         Arduino
65112           Linux
65112    Raspberry Pi
65112         Windows
dtype: object
```

Comment: thanks. how about combine 2 series, just keep the row have same index and value and save it into a new series? i am finding how to use combine but it seem not work. I want the result is series cause i want to use value_counts on it.

Comment: @robocon20x - It is not `s1.groupby([s1.index, s1]).size()` ? count by index and count by values of Series?

Comment: @robocon20x - because if use `s1.value_counts()` then lost information about original index

Comment: yes, sr about my question, i have edited it.  your code will help me know if a values appear in 2 series, count of it is 2 right?. And then i have to use for to caculate percent of it in ```df``` instead of use ```value_counts```

Comment: @robocon20x  hmmm, unfortuantely not understand. Maybe because still missing expected output from sample data. Can you add output with percentages like `s3` ? Another question, if use `print (s11.sort_values(ascending=False))` and `print (s22.sort_values(ascending=False))` all values are `1` in both ?

Comment: haha, sr. i have added output of s3. Thanks

Comment: @robocon20x - Super, what about `print (s11.sort_values(ascending=False))` and `print (s22.sort_values(ascending=False))` ?

Comment: @robocon20x - Adde EDIT to answer.

Comment: in SQL, it is INTERSECT between 2 table (columns here is index and value), but i dont know what it is in python, i tried merge but it seem not work cause it only have index and values in series,.

Comment: @robocon20x - I create `MultiIndex` so possible use `Index.intersection`

Comment: oh, your edit code seem work. thanks . python have too much func() :((, my teacher don't let me use for loop to solve the problem. thanks again